# algorithm - Find the cheapest consecutive row of seats on a bus?

Tags: algorithm

While practicing for interviews I came across this question and I have absolutly no idea how to approach it.

I want to say it's a graph problem (find the cheapest path maybe?) but I can't be certain.

How should one appraoch a problem like this? Are there solutions to any similar problems.

Edit- 
some extra info:

input is a file containing the position of each seat, wether they are already taken and the price of the seat. Consecutive meaning pairs of seats in front or behind each other.

Due to this being a question someone else was asked and was retelling I dont have access to actual input.

Comment: Could you clarify the question with an example input and solution?

Comment: If I encountered this question in an interview - I would ask for more information. So - what do you mean by "consecutive row of seat" , how are prices calculated, give me a demo bus with prices rows, and an expected outcome so I understand what you want from me ... please.

Comment: **consecutive and row** hmm, in each row you can have two seats on one side in normal bus :D

Comment: Without more information, this just sounds like you can go through all rows and keep track of the cheapest consecutive row or pair of rows. But that's me making assumptions about what this hypothetical bus looks like and what the problem is actually asking for - we really need an image and input and output to explain this. If you don't have access to actual input and output, you should create some example input and output based on how you understand the problem.